# Animate an image with a button in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

Pretty basic question, I have been trying to animate an image by clicking a button, been looking over all the answers on this site since its a common question, but can't seem to find out why it isn't working...I have bootstrap enabled. Here is the code. If you provide a solution perhaps you can tell me what I did wrong in your fix. New to programming, started 2 weeks ago, and damn, this stuff is cool! here is the code:

```
<img id="GBAlexImg" src="GBAlexSm.png" 
style="left:140px;top:120px;position:absolute;opacity:1.0;">

$("#GBAlexAtk").on("click", function(){

    $("#GBAlexImg").animate({height:"300px"}, function(){
        $("#GBAlexImg".animate({left: "100", top: "120"});
            });

<a href="#" id="GBAlexAtk" class="btn btn-primary">Attack</a>
```

UPDATE: I changed the code, so here is what it looks like now. For some reason, it STILL doesn't animate...

The image loaded on a canvas:

```
<img id="GBAlexImg" src="GBAlexSm.png" style="left:140px;top:120px;position:absolute;opacity:1.0;">
```

The button (through bootstrap):

```
<div id="monster1" class="monster-controls">           
        <a id="GBAlexAtk" class="btn btn-primary">Attack</a>
</div>
```

The animate function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#GBAlexAtk').click(function(){
            $('#GBAlexImg').animate({height:300}, 500, function(){
                $('#GBAlexImg').animate({left:'500', top:'120'}, 500);
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Learn to use the console, you have syntax errors, for instance you're missing a parenthesis in `$("#GBAlexImg".animate` and closing functions etc.

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/ will make your life easir

Comment: I have firebug installed. Not sure how I can use it to find my error? And I'm not sure where I am missing the parenthesis.

Comment: If you have firebug installed, simply click the firebug icon and click the console tab. If you don't see a firebug icon, right click the toolbar and click 'adjust' or something like that. Now drag the icon into the toolbar at the spot you like.

Comment: I am actually using chrome, so it's got firebug built in. My question is how do I use it to find out why my code doesn't animate the image?

Comment: Usually the console window in the browser web dev tool will tell you (in bright red) if he stumbled upon an error while executing the code. Something the explication is clear and other times it could be pretty vague, and in this case you will have to search a little bit more. Normally the console will point out a line number in your code, so you can examine your code and start from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I do hope your JQuery code is placed in a 'script' tag on the page, and not like you added in your post. Note that I'm kinda projecting/guessing, since I haven't seen your entire html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//ADD Jquery code here...
</script>
```

Second of all, you need to enclose your JQuery code inside the JQuery Document Ready event. [SOURCE](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> The handler passed to the method is guaranteed to be executed after the
>   DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other
>   event handlers and run other jQuery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //ADD Jquery code here...
    });
</script>
```

Next, you seem to be missing a lot of parameters for the animate method. You should [read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Note that the easing parameter is not mandatory.

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
Which means :
$("#GBAlexImg").animate({left: "100", top: "120"}, 500, function(){ //OnComplete code });
```

Knowing all this, your full JQuery code (included inside the script tag) should look like this:

```
//Document ready
$(function(){
    $('#GBAlexAtk').click(function(){
        $('#GBAlexImg').animate({height:300}, 500, function(){
            $('#GBAlexImg').animate({left:'200', top:'120'}, 500);
        });
    });
});
```

You can take a look at a [**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aD3Cd/)

Comment: I tried exactly what you said, even with all the parathesis, and it still doesn't animate...is there anything else I'm doing wrong? Definitely imported jQuery. I attached my revised code in the original post.

Comment: Ok.. then when you load the page, open Chrome's web dev tool console window and check to see if you have any errors. Hit the button to execute the click event and check to console to see if it gives any error. [Here is an example of a console error](http://i61.tinypic.com/4jxa1y.jpg). Check this out and get back to me with what you found

Comment: Alright! It worked, thanks IndieRok! I had to move the import file for jQuery to the top of the page inside head.

Comment: Great! Glad I could be of help.